# Display tabs on user page without page reload

Tags: feature-request

Currently, when I use the various tabs on my user screen (stats, recent, etc.) the entire page reloads and I lose my sort settings on them. I think it is possible to do an AJAX page update in place instead of the full reload efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh... I'm not against this, so long as i can still link to individual pages.

But i'm not sure it'd do any good; it'd mean reloading almost the entire page anyway...

BTW: what's with the bounty?

Comment: I know there could be potential drawbacks, but I haven't seen the code behind. My FR was unanswered for 3 days and I had excess rep, to at least draw some opinions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was just frustrated with that very aspect this morning.  User tab settings should stay where they are set as the User's new default.